# Python Почему не работает функция?

Tags: python, django

Решил засунуть получение статьи, рубрики и тегов в одну функцию, а она почему то не работает. То ошибка, то 404:

```
def article(request, alies):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['article'] = get_object_or_404(Article, alies=alies)
    if args['article'] == Http404:
        head_id = get_object_or_404(Heading, heading_alies=alies)
        args['article'] = Article.objects.filter(article_heading=head_id.id)
        if not args['article']:
            tag_id = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag_alies=alies)
            args['article'] = Article.objects.filter(tags=tag_id.id)
        else:

    else:

    args['heading'] = Heading.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('article.html', args)
```

Comment: ну так Http404 это не код возврата, а исключение, т.е. его ловить и обрабатывать надо как исключения. Подробности можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) (обратите внимание на *This example is equivalent to...*

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если статьи нет get_object_or_404(Article, alies=alies) уже вернёт 404, если хотите обрабатывать это исключение, вам нужна другая конструкция:

```
    try:
         args['article'] = Article.objects.get(alies=alies)
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        # тут ваша логика обработки 404
```

вот это вызовет ошибку:

```
else:
```

если нет условия "иначе" его можно просто не писать, если его нет временно, то можно поставить там заглушки:

```
else:
    pass
```

Comment: *если хотите обрабатывать это исключение, вам **нужна** другая конструкция* - а почему именно "нужна"? Чем исходный вариант с `try... except Http404...` не подходит?

Comment: Ну собственно подходит, не подумал об этом, только смысл его использовать? Исходный вариант имеет совершенно конкретную задачу - вывести страницу 404 если объект не найден, если у нас задача другая логичнее сделать так, как я написал